# Infinite Recursion When Trying To Splice A Vuex Array

Tags: javascript, vuex

I have a codesandbox setup up [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/ll77lmyxxq) which should be printing off three dates.

The most relevent pieces of code are:

```
import Vue from "vue";
import App from "./App";
import Vuex from "vuex";
Vue.use(Vuex);

const { DateTime } = require("luxon");
Vue.config.productionTip = false;

var store = new Vuex.Store({
  debug: true,
  state: {
    dateTimes: [
      { startTime: DateTime.local(), meta: "test" },
      { startTime: DateTime.local().plus({ days: 2 }), meta: "test" }
    ]
  },
  mutations: {
    addItem(state) {
      var test = {
        startTime: DateTime.local().plus({ days: 1 }),
        meta: "test"
      };
      for (var i = 0; i < state.dateTimes.length; i++) {
        if (state.dateTimes[i].startTime > test.startTime) {
          state.dateTimes.splice(i, 0, state.dateTimes);
        }
      }
      state.dateTimes.push(test);
    }
  }
});

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  store: store,
  components: { App },
  template: "<App/>",
  created: function() {
    this.$store.commit("addItem");
  }
});
```

The specific error message I get is `Error in render: "InternalError: too much recursion"`

What is the correct way to splice in item in Vuex array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the problem `state.dateTimes.splice(i, 0, state.dateTimes);` You're always adding the same dates back in as `state.dateTimes` will have the values in as the slice operation hasn't affected the array yet.

Simple solution is to remove it to be `state.dateTimes.splice(i, 0, test);` This may not be the solution you want but it will fix the max call stack error